# Get pipe() state JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pipe, ytdl

I'm trying to code an Application that's able to download YouTube-Videos in multiple formats.
Everything is ok, except for getting the progress in percentage, I don't want the app to call a custom server by a request to get it. I'm using the ytdl-core JavaScript-Library.

I've thought of getting the current filesize and creating a loading effect by listening for the pipes state (IsWriting, IsCancelled) but how exacly do i do that? Here's the pipe:

```
...().pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path));
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `.on('progress')` event. There is a working example: [progress.js](https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core/blob/master/example/progress.js)